# How do I find the length (size) of a binary blob?

Tags: sqlite, size, blob

I have an SQLite table that contains a BLOB I need to do a size/length check on. How do I do that?

According to documentation `length(blob)` only works on texts and will stop counting after the first NULL. My tests confirmed this. I'm using SQLite 3.4.2.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I haven't had this problem, but you could try `length(hex(glob))/2`

**Update (Aug-2012):**
For SQLite 3.7.6 (released April 12, 2011) and later, `length(blob_column)` works as expected with both text and binary data.

Answer (score 13):

for me `length(blob)` works just fine, gives the same results like the other.

Comment: For a binary blob? That would be in violation of the SQLite documentation which says blobs are treated as text and as such length() is accurate only until it finds a `\0` character.

Comment: The current documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html says "The length(X) function returns the length of X in characters if X is a string, or in bytes if X is a blob."

Answer (score 10):

As an additional answer, a common problem is that sqlite effectively ignores the column type of a table, so if you store a string in a blob column, it becomes a *string column for that row*. As length works different on strings, it will then only return the number of characters before the final 0 octet. It's easy to store strings in blob columns because you normally have to cast explicitly to insert a blob:

```
insert into table values ('xxxx'); // string insert
insert into table values(cast('xxxx' as blob)); // blob insert
```

to get the correct length for values stored as string, you can cast the length argument to blob:

```
select length(string-value-from-blob-column); // treast blob column as string
select length(cast(blob-column as blob)); // correctly returns blob length
```

The reason why length(hex(blob-column))/2 works is that hex doesn't stop at internal 0 octets, and the generated hex string doesn't contain 0 octets anymore, so length returns the correct (full) length.

Answer (score 4):

Example of a `select` query that does this, getting the length of the blob in column `myblob`, in table `mytable`, in row 3:

```
select length(myblob) from mytable where rowid=3;
```

Answer (score 2):

LENGTH() function in sqlite 3.7.13 on Debian 7 does not work, but LENGTH(HEX())/2 works fine.

```
# sqlite --version
3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22 f5b5a13f7394dc143aa136f1d4faba6839eaa6dc

# sqlite xxx.db "SELECT docid, LENGTH(doccontent), LENGTH(HEX(doccontent))/2 AS b FROM cr_doc LIMIT 10;"
1|6|77824
2|5|176251
3|5|176251
4|6|39936
5|6|43520
6|494|101447
7|6|41472
8|6|61440
9|6|41984
10|6|41472
```

Answer (score 0):

Although [`length()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) should return bytes for BLOBs, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250940/how-do-i-find-the-length-size-of-a-binary-blob#31896266) explains why it may not. One way is to use the [`STRICT`](https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html) clause on the table. Other way is to use [`octet_length()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#octet_length) that has recently been added in [3.43.1](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_43_1.html).