# How to test if a blob in an sqlite table is not null, without reading the blob entirely?

Tags: sql, sqlite, blob

I am trying to query a table that has a blob column, and need to filter the results to only provide rows that have content (any content) in the blob column.

However, doing `SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE blob_column IS NOT NULL` takes a long time, which I assume is due to the fact that some of the blobs are quite heavy. It seems that the WHERE clause is reading the entire content of the blobs and comparing them to `null`.

Is there a way to test whether a blob column is null or not, without having sqlite read the entire contents of the blob?

Comment: There's a related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899363, where the asker was looking to get the actual size of the blob, rather than merely whether it was empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [version 3.7.12](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_12.html), using the [length()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) or [typeof()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof) functions avoids reading the binary data (the query is much faster). So to avoid the unnecessary overhead, one must change

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE blob_column IS NOT NULL
```

to

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE LENGTH(blob_column) IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE TYPEOF(blob_column) != 'null'
```

Comment: Wow!  That is highly non-intuitive.

Comment: For me only `LENGTH(blob_column) != 0` worked

Comment: Do you mean `TYPEOF` did not work and you had to use `LENGTH`, or `'null'` did not work and you had to use `0`?

Comment: I mean all `TYPEOF(blob_column) != 'null'`, `blob_column IS NOT NULL`, `LENGTH(blob_column) IS NOT NULL` did not give me proper results - rows with empty blob_column were displayed. The only option that worked was the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use  sqlite3_blob_read()
On success returns SQLITE_OK. Otherwise, an error code