# DATALENGTH SQL function for (utf-8) TEXT in Sqlite?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm using the C interface to SQLite and need to list the size of the a string stored in `TEXT` column, i.e. what some databases would support using

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(body) FROM table;
```

However, SQLite does not have the `DATALENGTH` function. Since the text in question is quite large, I want to avoid loading the actual `body` column from disk. Since the `TEXT` is utf8, [`LENGTH(body)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) does not return the desired result (it does return the character count, whereas I need to know the storage size). Converting the column to `BLOB` is not an option because the database is created by a third-party program.

**Q:** Is there any way to obtain this information directly from the database, short of writing a [custom SQL function](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)? The SQLite [file format](https://sqlite.org/fileformat.html) does store the length of `TEXT` fields, so I'd be surprised if this information really isn't exposed.

**Related:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6983927/3451198
- [How do I find the length (size) of a binary blob in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/250940/3451198)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast to a blob to get the size in bytes from `length()`:

```
SELECT length(cast(body AS BLOB)) FROM table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `cast`, I've been browsing the docs a bit and it should do the trick! Looking at the sqlite3 source superficially suggests that no new memory will be allocated in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @Shawn's answer, it turns out that implementing a custom SQL function is actually fairly simple:

```
/* Implement the DATALENGTH() SQL function. Code adapted from the SQLite source
 * for the LENGTH() function.
 */
static void db_sqlite_datalength(sqlite3_context *context, int argc,
        sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    (void) argc;

    switch(sqlite3_value_type(argv[0])) {
    case SQLITE_BLOB:
    case SQLITE_INTEGER:
    case SQLITE_FLOAT:
    case SQLITE_TEXT:
        sqlite3_result_int(context, sqlite3_value_bytes(argv[0]));
        break;
    default:
        sqlite3_result_null(context);
        break;
    }
}

static int db_register_custom_functions(sqlite3 *db)
{
    return sqlite3_create_function(db, "datalength", 1,
            SQLITE_UTF8 | SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC, NULL,
            &db_sqlite_datalength, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Since the builtin `length` function is implemented in exactly the same way, performance should be alright. I browsed the sqlite3 source a bit, but it is not so easy to tell when exactly disk accesses happen. Presumably, sqlite3 `mmap`s everything such that the important thing for performance is that possible overflow pages for long `TEXT` fields are not accessed unnecessarily.